# Jest Error with Bugsnag Library for react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, bugsnag

Facing issue with bugsnag mocking in react native

Error -

> FAIL  **tests**/App-test.js   ● renders correctly
>
> ```
> TypeError: _reactNative.default.start is not a function
>
>   40 |     // StatusBar.setBackgroundColor(blueVersion.secondary);
>   41 |     // StatusBar.setTranslucent(true);
> > 42 |     Bugsnag.start();
>      |             ^
>   43 |     UserExperior.startRecording(CONFIG_KEYS['USER_EXPERIOR_KEY']);
>   44 |     deviceData();
>   45 |     SplashScreen.hide();
>
>   at src/App.js:42:13
>   at commitHookEffectListMount (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:12999:26)
>   at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14422:11)
>   at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14382:9)
>   at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14369:7)
>   at commitPassiveMountEffects (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14357:3)
>   at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:16248:3)
>   at flushPassiveEffects (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:16197:14)
>   at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15413:3)
>   at flushSyncCallbacks (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2597:22)
> ```
>
> Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
> Snapshots:   0 total Time:        1.235s, estimated 2s

Solution Tried -

```
jest.mock('@bugsnag/react-native', () => ({
  use(plugin) {
    const boundary = plugin.init();
    // we don't need the error boundary to swallow the errors, we want jest see them and fail the test
    delete boundary.prototype.componentDidCatch;
    return boundary;
  },
}));
```

In jest setup js yet not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had a lot of problems with calls to `Bugsnag` in the jest environment. Ultimately solved it by manually mocking it in `__mocks__/@bugsnag/react-native.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  addOnError: jest.fn(),
  notify: jest.fn(),
  // add other functions here if you need them
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For `jestsetup.js` (aka jest-setup.js, or jest.setup.js), this alternative approach also works:

```js
jest.mock("@bugsnag/react-native", () => ({
  leaveBreadcrumb: jest.fn(),
  notify: jest.fn(),
  start: jest.fn(),
}));
```

https://dev.to/bytehala/how-to-mock-bugsnag-in-jestsetupjs-c79